# json obj from asp.net mvc to canvas.js chart

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, object, canvas

I searched in similar posts, but can not find a solution !! 
In my asp.net mvc controller, I have a method: public object OfferChart()

```
List<Det> obj = new List<Det>();

            foreach (DataRow dro in dt.Rows)
            {
                Det def = new Det();
                def.xval = Convert.ToString(dro["Section"]);
                def.yval = Convert.ToDecimal(dro["Percent"]);
                obj.Add(def);
            }
            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

What I want, is to send the dates from obj in a javascript object, and use it instead dataPoints for my chart (canvas) :

```
function chartOfferSections() {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartOfferSections", {
            theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
            exportEnabled: true,
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Oferte pe sectoare"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "pie",
                startAngle: 25,
                toolTipContent: "<b>{label}</b>: {y}%",
                showInLegend: "true",
                legendText: "{label}",
                indexLabelFontSize: 16,
                indexLabel: "{label} - {y}%",
                dataPoints: 
                [
                    { y: 25.00, label: "Sectorul 1" },
                    { y: 25.00, label: "Sectorul 2" },
                    { y: 25.00, label: "Sectorul 3" },
                    { y: 25.00, label: "Sectorul 4" }
                ]
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
}
```

Find something examples and tried to implement, but no work

```
var dataPts[];
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "Json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("OfferChart")',
    data: obj,
    success: function (data) {
        var len = data.d.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            dataPts.push({
                label: data.d[i].xval,
                y: data.d[i].yval
            });
        }
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting responses? Errors?

Comment: no error, just all my charts dissapeared. Work with Visual Studio, but breakpoints are uselles in js file

Answer (score 0):

at the end of you success function you need to assign your temp dataPts to the chart options like this

```
chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = dataPts
```

then call `chart.render();`

Comment: finally I used ViewBag. In controller ViewBag.DataPoints = jsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList) and in View ( in script) : DataPoints = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints). The problem is that the script must be in View, and not in separate file (.js) and inserted with <div id="chartName">